# How to set (title of) detail view with Ext navigation view

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

What's the proper way of setting the (title of) a detail view with an Ext navigation view?

**1st approach**

In the [Sencha list tutorial](https://github.com/senchalearn/Presidents) ([video](http://vimeo.com/37212149)) the controller does

```
this.getMain().push({
  xtype: 'presidentdetail',
  title: record.fullName(),
  data: record.getData()
});
```

and the [detail view](https://github.com/senchalearn/Presidents/blob/master/app/view/PresidentDetail.js) is a regular `Ext.Panel` with a tpl.

**2nd approach**

However, the [navigation view example](http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.2.0/examples/navigationview/index.html) that ships with the Sencha Touch download (code [here](https://github.com/ModusCreateOrg/sencha-touch-in-action-examples/tree/master/touch/examples/navigationview)) takes a totally different approach. Here the controller essentially does

```
this.showContact = Ext.create('AddressBook.view.contact.Show');
this.showContact.setRecord(record);
this.getMain().push(this.showContact);
```

and the detail view contains quite a bit of code I don't understand (yet)

```
Ext.define('AddressBook.view.contact.Show', {
  extend: 'Ext.Container',
  ...
  config: {
    title: 'Information',
    baseCls: 'x-show-contact',
    layout: 'vbox',

    items: [
      {
        id: 'content',
        tpl: ...
      },
      ...
  },
  updateRecord: function (newRecord) {
    if (newRecord) {
      this.down('#content').setData(newRecord.data);
       ..
    }
  }
});
```

**Confusion**

For a Sencha/Ext rookie like me this is confusing. What advantages does one approach have over the other? How are they different in what they achieve?

The first approach updates the title of the detail view (which effectively is the title in the navigation bar) in the controller. I have not yet found out how to do the same using second approach. Any hints?

Comment: Check out the docs on xtype: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#%21/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-xtype  The difference is between explicit and immediate object creation, and deferred creation. However, since both are happening within the context of the controller, I would imagine they would behave almost precisely the same.

Comment: RE: setting the title, you could do exactly the same thing in the second example like so: this.showContact = Ext.create( 'AddressBook.view.contact.Show', { title: 'sometitlehere' });

Comment: Thanks for the valuable feedback. After I added your title fix I realized how essentially the two approaches are different (besides what you pointed out). In the 2nd-approach-controller-code-snippet posted above I left out one crucial element. The controller stores a reference to the created detail view and only does `Ext.create` if it's null. In all other cases it just does `setRecord` and that's why the view itself overrides the `updateRecord` function. Therefore, your title fix only works the first time. I either need to instantiate the view every time or find a different solution.